# cannot get image info using https://graph.facebook.com/<photo_id>

Tags: facebook, photo, facebook-opengraph

The API always return false, without any detailed information.
Then same even when using the photo IDs of my own photos.
However, the photo ID listed in the API document (the Coca Cola one) works without problems...

Answer (score 0):

Your call to FB is correct i.e.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID + accesstoken
```

will return a JSON response with info about your image and urls to download the image in different sizes.

Most likely reason for your problem is you haven't requested the "user_photos" permission from the app user.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful please upvote it. If you found the answer answered your question, please mark is as answered. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work